# MongoDB: OR operator

Tags: mongodb

This query results in 3 objects:

```
db.list.find({ "Visibility": 4 })
```

This is expected. Now, when I run this query my result is 0 objects:

```
db.list.find({ "$or" : [ { "Visibility": 4 } ] } )
```

I would expect the same result in both cases since, in my understanding, a OR would be true if any one of the conditions are true.

So.. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done the same test as @AdaTheDev in `1.6.5` mongo version and got expected results.
So i suppose that you using mongodb version before `1.5.3` that does not support `$or` at all.

> The $or operator lets you use a boolean or expression to do queries.
>   You give $or a list of expressions,
>   any of which can satisfy the query.
>         **New in MongoDB 1.5.3**

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Yeah, i see. +1 also.

Comment: Yeah, that was my issue. Now running 1.8 and everything runs as expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

That looks find to me - a quick test here shows that does work.

Here's the whole test I ran:

```
db.Test.insert({_id: 1, Visibility: 1})
db.Test.insert({_id: 2, Visibility: 4})
db.Test.insert({_id: 3, Visibility: 3})
db.Test.insert({_id: 4, Visibility: 4})
db.Test.find({$or : [{Visibility: 4}]})
```

Sure enough, it returns _ids 2 and 4 as expected. I'm using 1.8.0, which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks AdaTheDev! I tried your exact test and it still fails. I'm running the one that's in the repo of Ubuntu 10.10, which is v1.4.4. I will upgrade and post my results in a while.

Comment: @Mika - aha, that be the problem then :) See Bugai13's answer - should work as soon as you upgrade

Comment: You were right, it wasn't implemented in 1.4.4. Now everything runs fine, thank you for the help :)